# Validar Estado de una petición Rest Ionic2

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
this.http.post("http://api/user", JSON.stringify(this.params), options)
            .subscribe(
            res => this.obj = res,//info = res,
            err => console.error(err),
);
```

Si esta peticion me devuelve un 200 quiero avanzar a otra ventana y tengo esto

```
if (this.obj.status == 200){
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
  }
```

Pero `this.obj.status` es undefined

Como puedo tener el valor de status fuera de la petición?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si envía una solicitud HTTP, devuelve un Observable, que es asíncrono. Esto significa que la llamada `.subscribe ()` terminará antes de que la respuesta vuelva; No es bloqueante. Todo después de la `.subscribe ()` se ejecutará inmediatamente.

Por lo tanto, debe realizar su redirección condicional dentro de su `.subscribe ().` El bloque dentro se ejecutará sólo cuando la solicitud se resuelva (con un resultado o un error)

```
.subscribe(
  res => {
   if (res.status === 200) {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
   }
  }
  err => ...
)
```

Para mas Información se pueden basar en https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

En tu pregunta no lo muestras, pero asumo que haces la POST http en una función aparte y no estas empleando ningún método para controlar el flujo de datos en tu aplicación.

Typescript funciona de forma asíncrona, por lo el orden en que escribes el código no necesariamente es el orden en que se ejecuta, especialmente cuando llamas a funciones.

```
httpPost() {
  return new Promise(respuesta => {
    this.http.post("http://api/user", JSON.stringify(this.params), options)
      .subscribe(res => {
         //info = res
         respuesta(res);
      },err => {
         console.error(err);
    });
  });
}
```

Para llamar la función puede hacer esto en donde necesitas el contenido de tu variable.

```
this.httpPost().then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  if (res.status === 200) {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
  }
});
```